# Is it possible to wake a user Process from a kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

I have  a user level process which is sleeping currently, by using `sleep()` function. I am trying to write a kernel module which can first extract the `task_struct` of the user process from its PID, and then can wake the process. Till date I have implemented the code for getting the task_struct from PID. But, I dont know of any function which can wake up that process. I tried `wake_up_process(task_struct)`, though its returning 1, i.e, success in waking up the process, but the the `printf()` statement just after the sleep() statement of the user process is not getting executed. Will changing the `state` of the task_struct help? Or there's some another approach for doing the same? Please guide me further.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but you might be going about it the wrong way. sleep() waits on a delay, and even though you could signal the process from within the kernel (essentially like kill(2) in user mode, with some non harmful signal, but something that will "kick you out" of the system call, the correct way of doing so is having the sleeping process block on a device which your kernel module exports. This way, the kernel module will have control - the process will be stuck in a read(2) call, and until your read implmentation in the module returns, the process will be stuck.

This is preferable, because the whole idea of sleeping is when you are waiting for something. When you simple sleep(xxxx) indefinitely, you're basically waiting on a time out. What more, using the device approach, you can add the file descriptor to a select(2)/poll(2) loop, as well, which makes for very elegant synchronization with other input/output descriptors.

Comment: That means, according to you, instead of using sleep, I should use a 'read', such that, the process gets blocked. So, my kernel module will basically then unblock the process to make it read that file. But, I didnt understood, how will my kernel unblock it. Does sending signals from the kernel module help? Isnt there any function for ding the same?

Comment: To reiterate: if you just use "sleep" you can wake with a signal (technically SIGALRM). But the read method is preferred. The flow is simple: you create a character device driver. The user mode process calls read(2) on the device driver. When it calls read, your read handler in the module is invoked. From that point on, your module has the control of your process, as its code is running in that process/thread context. No function for doing same, because "sleep" is not meant to be woken up on an event, but after a timeout. Reading from an FD, however, is designed for it.